# fit an interaction term to each preceding variable

Tags: r, lm

Is there a way in R to fit an interaction term to each preceding variable in the model specification?
I would like to do the following, but in a more concise way.

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars)
mod1<-lm(mpg~ cyl+disp+hp+wt+cyl:wt+disp:wt+hp:wt, data=mtcars)
summary(mod1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to arithmetic.

```
f1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt + cyl:wt + disp:wt + hp:wt, data=mtcars)
f2 <- lm(mpg ~ (cyl + disp + hp)*wt, data=mtcars)

stopifnot(all.equal(f1$coe, f2$coe))
```

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
mod1<-lm(mpg~ (cyl+disp+hp+wt)^2, data=mtcars)
```